# Infinite series for which interchanging order of summation is false

Tags: sequences-and-series

In D.Knuth book, given interchanging order of summation equation:

$\sum_{R(i)}$$\sum_{S(j)} a_{ij}$ = $\sum_{R(j)}$$\sum_{S(i)} a_{ij}$

I need to find example of infinite series in which this equation in false.
The author gives example of such series as:

Let $a_{(i+1)i}$ = +1 and $a_{i(i+1)}$ = -1, for all i>=0, and all other $a_{ij}$ = zero, let R(i) = S(i) = "i>=0". The left-hand side is -1 and the right-hand side is +1.

I can't imagine what he mean by "$a_{(i+1)i}$ = +1 and $a_{i(i+1)}$ = -1", I can't see j index and if j depends on i how relations R(i) and S(i) looks like. Can anyone put more light on this answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the definition is clearer if I write it as follows:

$$a_{ij}=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }i=j+1\\
-1,&\text{if }i=j-1\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Then you’re looking at an infinite matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0&-1&0&0&0&0&\ldots\\
1&0&-1&0&0&0&\ldots\\
0&1&0&-1&0&0&\ldots\\
0&0&1&0&-1&0&\ldots\\
0&0&0&1&0&-1&\ldots\\
0&0&0&0&1&0&\ldots\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&\ldots\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&\ldots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{bmatrix}$$

zeroes on the diagonal, $1$s on the first subdiagonal, $-1$s on the first superdiagonal, and zeroes everywhere else. The top row is row $0$, and the lefthand column is column $0$. Thus,

$$\sum_{j\ge 0}a_{ij}$$

is the sum across row $i$, so

$$\sum_{j\ge 0}a_{ij}=\begin{cases}
-1,&\text{if }i=0\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Thus,

$$\sum_{i\ge 0}\sum_{j\ge 0}a_{ij}=-1+0+0+0+\ldots=-1\;.$$

Similarly,

$$\sum_{i\ge 0}a_{ij}$$

is the sum down column $j$, so

$$\sum_{i\ge 0}a_{ij}=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }j=0\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\;,
\end{cases}$$

and

$$\sum_{j\ge 0}\sum_{i\ge 0}a_{ij}=1+0+0+0+\ldots=1\;.$$

Comment: Is the notation $\sum_{n\ge 0}a_n$ equivalent to the notation $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$? I have seen both here on the site, but I am not sure if they are equivalent.

Comment: @AOrtiz: Yes, they are synonymous.